# Is there a Vyper equivalent to OpenZeppelin's SafeERC20.safeTransfer?

Tags: erc-20, vyper

OpenZeppelin provides the [`SafeERC20`](https://github.com/nventuro/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/c008f1f0c61d0fa61cc81dc24465fbf808ffc7cf/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol#L16) Solidity library as a way to handle the [possible variations of ERC20](https://medium.com/loopring-protocol/an-incompatibility-in-smart-contract-threatening-dapp-ecosystem-72b8ca5db4da). Is there an equivalent way to do this using Vyper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Vyper `0.2.0` this is possible using the [`raw_call`](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.1/built-in-functions.html#raw_call) builtin function:

```py
@external
def safe_transfer(_token: address, _to: address, _value: uint256) -> bool:
    _response: Bytes[32] = raw_call(
        _token,
        concat(
            method_id("transfer(address,uint256)"),
            convert(_to, bytes32),
            convert(_value, bytes32)
        ),
        max_outsize=32
    )
    if len(_response) > 0:
        assert convert(_response, bool), "Transfer failed!"

    return True
```